# Software to help organize and plan self study (KMS+LMS)

Tags: knowledge-organization, learning

I basically have many topics with many resources that I want to study on my own (a pile of books, YouTube videos, podcasts, Udemy course, websites, ...). The materials of different topics are inter-related, so just working down the list from top to bottom is not ideal. When studying at university, the material and schedule/tasks are predefined more or less by the teachers. In my case, it's like a custom study program with only the things that are relevant / are of interest to me (covering areas like ecology, economics, math, geology, philosophy, and history).

LMS (learning management system) tools like Moodle are good to create courses with content. KMS (knowledge management system) tools like Obisidian or TheBrain are good at managing information and the connections between it. I usually take notes in MS Word for each book/video and also per topic.

Currently, I started an Excel file with all the topics to study and resources I found and also the time I estimate is needed to study a resource.

I couldn't find software where I could specify topics (or courses) with the resources I found and then plan the study. Since it takes many months (more like several years according to Excel) to study all the material and the topics are related, a simple Excel file has its limits. For example, it is hard to check what should be done when and if I'm still on schedule.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this suites your request, but for me Notion is the best platform for project planning, you can custom it whatever you like and create specific pages for each course.But for the task tracking I recommend Bordio https://bordio.com/. In Bordio, you can write down all the tasks for the week ahead, and everything will be visible on one board. You can also select due dates and create task estimations, write plans and ideas on the waiting list, which opens on the side of the screen and set them later. Hope it will help you!